# Matlab's Quiver3 plots only 4 vectors

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph, 3d

I want to use the command quiver3(X,Y,Z,M,N,O)
in order to get a vector field, where all matrices are 10x10x10 arrays with real entries. Now I wanted to plot it and got only 4 vectors instead of my expected 1000. Does anybody here know, what I could possibly have done wrong?
If you need further information, I am available for your comments.

Comment: I would post some code...

Comment: oh hi, it's you again. well I wanted to make a 3D vector field plot from the data, that we discussed yesterday

Comment: so X,Y,Z are the meshgrid of x,y,z, where they are taken as some linspace, then I evaluated my vector field E(i,j,k,:) at all those combinations X(i,j,k),...,Z(i,j,k). Then I saved M=real(E(:,:,:,1)),...,O=real(E(:,:,:,3)) and used the quiver 3 command

Comment: have you evaluated the full vector space so that you have 6D data now?

Comment: 6D? they are all, as I said 10x10x10...

Comment: Yes but at each point you evaluate a 3D vector, so your data should be 6D, 3 spatial coordinates corresponding to the meshgrid (X,Y,Z) and 3 coordinates corresponding to vector orientation

Comment: okay, that's is what I did, if I understand you correctly. Do you see any mistakes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35063/discussion-between-try-hard-and-lipschitz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the problem occurs when attempting to display the data (rather than with attempting to display unallowed numerical values such as `Inf` or `NaN`), I think the problem is the range of norms of the vectors, such that only 4 show up.

The importance of the norm of the vectors relative to the range of the coordinate system is important, as illustrated by the following example:

Here all 10 random vectors show up:

```
Na = 10;
[X Y Z M N O] = deal(rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1)); 
quiver3(X,Y,Z,M,N,O)
```

[image]

But if some of the vectors are made 100 x bigger, only the smaller ones show up:

```
mul = 1e+3;
[X Y Z M N O] = deal(rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1),...
    [mul*rand(Na/2,1);rand(Na/2,1)],...
    [mul*rand(Na/2,1);rand(Na/2,1)],...
    [mul*rand(Na/2,1);rand(Na/2,1)]);
quiver3(X,Y,Z,M,N,O)
```

[image]

Similarly if some of the vectors are made too small they don't show up:

```
mul = 1e-3;
[X Y Z M N O] = deal(rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1),rand(Na,1),...
    [mul*rand(Na/2,1);rand(Na/2,1)],...
    [mul*rand(Na/2,1);rand(Na/2,1)],...
    [mul*rand(Na/2,1);rand(Na/2,1)]);
quiver3(X,Y,Z,M,N,O)
```

[image]

Vectors too large or too small relative to the axis are not displayed at all.

If it is a problem with scaling you may want to inspect your function and see how to narrow the range of x,y,z so that the vectors have a narrower range of values, or change the scale (logarithm?) so that all the data can be displayed in one figure.

**edit**

As an alternative to the question of how to display your data, you may want to consider using `isosurfaces`. Here's an example, with each red sphere representing a different isosurface in a spherical potential:

[image]